# How to add data to all log records in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, monolog

I would like to add some data to all log records within my Laravel application.

I think it would be helpful to know the username of the current user and/or the client IP address.

Currently I'm adding it manually by doing:

```
Log::info('Pre-paid activation.', array('username' => Auth::user()->username));
```

But I would like to know how to do add a listener or something to make *all* log recorde have the username (if available).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Laravel comes out of box with [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog), it is pretty straight forward. It can be easily achieved by editing `app/start/global.php` and add the following after the line that starts with: `Log::useFiles`:

```
Log::useFiles(storage_path().'/logs/laravel.log');
$monolog = Log::getMonolog();
$monolog->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
    $record['extra']['user'] = Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->username : 'anonymous';
    $record['extra']['ip'] = Request::getClientIp();
    return $record;
});
```

Basically, we are using the underlying Monolog instance to register a processor which will intercept any log record to be written. The results will be similar as the followings:

> [2014-04-12 23:07:35] local.INFO: Pre-paid activation. [] {"user":"anonymous","ip":"::1"}

More information about Monolog processors: https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/01-usage.md#using-processors

---

**Extra:** The hardcoded `extra` is to tell Monolog to add data as extra piece of information (redundant to say). In the practice, this is to avoid overriding any context data added in the original log call.

Comment: For Laravel 5, just create  LogServiceProvider, add it to your config/app.php, and add the same $monolog code into the boot() method.

Comment: @Davidos, for Laravel 5.6+, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032203/how-to-add-data-to-all-log-records-in-laravel-5-6/52032829#52032829

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 5 you can do it by customising Monolog. First create a class which customises Monolog so it adds the user information to the log records:

```
namespace App\Logging;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Log\Logger;

class AddUserInformation
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request = null)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function __invoke(Logger $logger)
    {
        if ($this->request) {
            foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
                $handler->pushProcessor([$this, 'processLogRecord']);
            }
        }
    }

    public function processLogRecord(array $record): array
    {
        $record['extra'] += [
            'user' => $this->request->user()->username ?? 'guest',
            'ip' => $this->request->getClientIp()
        ];

        return $record;
    }
}
```

Then connect the class to the Laravel logger by adding it to the channel setup in the `config/logging.php` file:

```
// ...
'channels' => [
    'single' => [
        'driver' => 'single',
        'tap' => [\App\Logging\AddUserInformation::class],
        'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
    ],
    // ...
]
```

[A documentation about customising Monolog](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels)

Answer (score -1):

For those looking for laravel 7.x it's explained here in the official doc https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/logging#customizing-monolog-for-channels

edit config\logging.php and add this to the channel you want to log to:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
...
'stack' => [
...
   'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter::class],
],
```

then create file App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Logging;

use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class CustomizeFormatter
{
    public function __invoke($logger)
    {
        foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
            $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter('custom logging - %level_name% %message% %context% %extra%'));
        }
    }
}
```