# How to add data to all log records in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

[How to add data to all log records in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23037393/how-to-add-data-to-all-log-records-in-laravel) answers how to add data to all log records in Laravel 5.5 and earlier. e.g. the following is added to AppServiceProvider::register():

```
$monolog = \Log::getMonolog();
$monolog->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
    $record['extra']['ip'] = \Request::getClientIp();
    $record['extra']['path'] = \Request::path();
    return $record;
});
```

This doesn't work for Laravel 5.6. I looked through the documentation for 'creating custom channels' but didn't see any obvious way to get the above behavior.

The error occurs from

> > @php artisan package:discover -v

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Call to undefined method Monolog\Logger::getMonolog()

at ...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\Logger.php: 273
269:      * @return mixed
270:      */
271:     public function __call($method, $parameters)
272:     {
273:         return $this->logger->{$method}(...$parameters);
274:     }
275: }
276:

Exception trace:

1   Illuminate\Log\Logger::__call("getMonolog", [])

...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Log\LogManager.php : 609

2   Illuminate\Log\LogManager::__call("getMonolog", [])

...\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php : 223

Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I am far from an expert at this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to put the code?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - what happens? Is there an error?

Comment: @ceejayoz  AppServiceProvider.php

Comment: @ChrisCousins, I'll update the question with the error message

Comment: Since Laravel 5.6 you should be using channels and a channel formatter to customize your logs - see docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging#advanced-monolog-channel-customization

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I solved this.

1. In .env, use the 'stack channel' for logging (i.e. 'LOG_CHANNEL=stack')
2. Add a 'tap' to a driver in config\logging.php

   ```
   'single' => [
       'driver' => 'single',
       'tap' => [App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter::class],
       'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
       'level' => 'debug',
   ]
   ```
3. Create App\Logging\CustomizeFormatter:

   ```
   namespace App\Logging;

   class CustomizeFormatter
   {
       public function __invoke($logger)
       {
           foreach ($logger->getHandlers() as $handler) {
               $handler->pushProcessor(function ($record) {
                   $record['extra']['ip'] = \Request::getClientIp();
                   $record['extra']['path'] = \Request::path();

                   return $record;
               });
           }
       }
   }
   ```