# Laravel: default additional info to all log

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, logging, monolog

I want to store this in all Log by default in Laravel 5.5:

```
$additionalInfo = auth()->user() ? 'Online user #'.auth()->user()->id : '';
```

Then an entry in `storage/logs/laravel.log` would look like this:

```
[2019-07-30 11:27:22] [Online user #1] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$metaInfo' (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: ...
```

Or this

```
[2019-07-30 11:27:22] local.ERROR: [Online user #1] Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$metaInfo' (T_VARIABLE) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Parse error: ...
```

Any idea on how can I accomplish it?

I feel that I need to create a [custom Monolog configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/errors#custom-monolog-configuration), by creating a custom Handler, but the Laravel docs don't go further showing us how to do it.

Comment: Is adding it in a line before the error is an option? ```[2019-07-30 11:27:22] local.INFO: Following error happened to Online user #1   ...[on antoher line]... [2019-07-30 11:27:22] local.ERROR: Parse error: syntax error```

Comment: @ElieMorin no, thank you for the idea!

Comment: did you find how to solve this? Because I think you have to overwrite the HandleException facade.

Comment: @ElieMorin yes, I've solved this, check the answer I just added! Overwriting HandlerException would work only for logging exceptions. I need it to work for any `Log::info($message)` I'd call in my app too.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032203/how-to-add-data-to-all-log-records-in-laravel-5-6/52032829#52032829

Comment: @ElieMorin it's only for Laravel 5.6, I am using 5.5 :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the best approach, but creating a new Log class to better handle logging the way I need it and registering the new class as `Log` alias in `config/app.php` has solved my issue.

New class `app/Log.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Log
{
  /**
     * Handle dynamic, static calls to the object.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array   $args
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public static function __callStatic($method, $args){
      // when it is called --> Log::info('hello world', ['more data' => 'Some additional data']);
      // parameters here will be --> $method = 'info'; $args[0] = 'hello world'; $args[1] = ['more data' => 'Some additional data'];
      $additionalData = isset($args[1]) ? $args[1] : [];
      if(auth()->check()){
        $additionalData['User ID'] = auth()->id();
      }
      return empty($additionalData) ? \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::$method($args[0]) : \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::$method($args[0], $additionalData);
    }
}
```

Then in `'aliases'` inside `config/app.php` I've changed this

```
'Log' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::class,
```

To this

```
'Log' => App\Log::class,
```

Now, any throwed exception or `Log::info($message)` called in my app will be handled by `app/Log.php` that properly includes the User ID just after and within the main message in logs when user is online.